# Mocking a parameterized constructor using powermockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

Consider the code given below:

```
@Override
public void A()  {
    objectA = objectB.B();
    objectA.C(someValue);
        objectC = new constructor(objectA,callback());
        //Rest of the code
    }

}
public Callback callback() {
    return new callback() {
        @Override
        public void someMethod(someArgument) {
            //some Code         
       }
    };
}
```

I am trying to write a unit test case where:

- the call `objectB.B()` has to be mocked
- the call to the constructor has to be mocked

This is what I have done using Mockito and Powermockito:

```
@InjectMocks
ClassBeingTested testObject;

@Mock
ClassB objectB;  

@Mock
ClassC objectC;    

@Before()
public void setup()  {
    when(objectB.B()).thenReturn(new ObjectA("someValue"));

    whenNew(objectC.class).withArguments(any(),any()).thenReturn(objectC);

}
@Test()
public void testMethod() {
    testObject.A();

}
```

The first mock successfully works but the second mock using `whenNew` fails with the following error:

> org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.ConstructorNotFoundException: No constructor found in class 'ClassC' with parameter types: [ null ]

If I use `withArguments(objectA, callback())` where I have the implementation of callback in my test class, the actual constructor is called.

I want to mock the constructor call and restrict the call to the actual constructor. How can I do that?

> I can not edit the code design since that is out of my scope.

Comment: error is clearly saying there is no constructor found in class C. So you cannot you whenNew()

Comment: It says that a particular type of constructor was not found. If I change the matchers used to some exact value then the actual constructor is called.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the **argument** matcher any()? In other words: don't explain half of your code --- instead edit your question and turn it into a [mcve] where we have **all** facts to worst case run the stuff ourselves!

Answer (score 1):

In short, you get the error due to usage of 2 generic **`any()`** matchers.

When you use `.withArguments(...)` and set both as **`any()`** it implies
`.withArguments(null, null)` (since any() may match pretty much anything including nulls) which folds eventually as a single null and reflection api (which PowerMock heavily relies on) fails to discover a suitable constructor for ClassC(null).

You may check out the source of `org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.AbstractConstructorExpectationSetup<T>`
 [source](https://www.javatips.net/api/powermock-master/api/mockito-common/src/main/java/org/powermock/api/mockito/internal/expectation/AbstractConstructorExpectationSetup.java) that does the job

To fix up the issue consider using either `.withAnyArguments()` if you do not care of param types and stubbing all available constructors **OR** specify more concrete types while using **`any()`** like so
`whenNew(ClassC.class).withArguments(any(ClassA.class), any(Callback.class))`